# How to replace certain rows in a data frame without using a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I'd like to replace certain rows of my variable group with blank. How can I do it without using a for loop? Here is my code. The goal is to code 'group' to be: "A", blank, blank, blank, blank, "A", blank, blank...

```
group <- rep("A", 20)
var   <- rep("B", 20)

out <- data.frame(group, var)

out$row_num <- seq(1:nrow(out))
    
for (i in 1:nrow(out)) {
   if (out$row_num[i] %% 5 != 1) {
      out$group[i] <- " "
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, correct. I've fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These operations are vectorized.  So, the replacement can be done without a `for` loop.  Also, from `R 4.0`, the default option while constructing `data.frame` is `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

```
out$group[out$row_num %% 5 != 1] <- ' '
```

---

Based on the update, if the intention is to replicate

```
rep(c("A", "", "", "", ""), length.out = 20)
#[1] "A" ""  ""  ""  ""  "A" ""  ""  ""  ""  "A" ""  ""  ""  ""  "A" ""  ""  ""  ""
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I intend to replicate.